# Using .NET shims to unit test datetime method

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, datetime

I have to test a method that calculates the time difference of the local time and UTC. So I've tried to use a shims in order to change the local time and UTC but this does not work. Here is my unit test code:

```
<TestMethod()> Public Sub CurrentTimeTest()

    'Arrange
    Dim expected As System.DateTime
    expected = New DateTime(2015, 3, 5, 20, 0, 0)
    Dim actual As DateTime
    actual = DateTime.Now
    'Act
    Using (ShimsContext.Create())
        System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.NowGet = Function() As System.DateTime
                                               Return New DateTime(2015, 3, 5, 20, 0, 0)
                                           End Function

        System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.UtcNowGet = Function() As System.DateTime
                                               Return New DateTime(2015, 3, 5, 15, 0, 0)
                                           End Function
    End Using

    'Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
End Sub
```

I cannot figure out why DateTime.Now is not equal to that I've set.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A better solution (IMO) would be to create an interface for "something that gives you the current time" (potentially just UTC) and inject that where you need it... you can then have a "production" implementation and "test" implementation. That's what we do for Noda Time... I've used it in a number of scenarios, and it's much cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `DateTime.Now` *before* you set up the shim... so it can't possibly retroactively change the value of `actual`. I suspect if you use:

```
Dim actual As DateTime
'Act
Using (ShimsContext.Create())
    System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.NowGet = Function() As System.DateTime
            Return New DateTime(2015, 3, 5, 20, 0, 0)
        End Function

    System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.UtcNowGet = Function() As System.DateTime
            Return New DateTime(2015, 3, 5, 15, 0, 0)
        End Function
    actual = DateTime.Now
End Using

'Assert
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
```

... then it'll work. But as noted in a comment, personally I would treat "I need the current time" as a dependency, and represent it in an interface (`IClock`). Then you can have different implementations for production and testing (or use mocks if you really want) just as you would for any other dependency.

Comment: Yes, it works now. Thank you. I know it is better to use interfaces but I am not the person who writes the code and I am not allowed to change it.

Comment: Do you have an idea whether using ToUniversalTime() function can hide DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow in such a way when I am trying to change them, the changes are not applied as shown above? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Rany: I really don't know what you mean, I'm afraid... but it sounds like a new question which should have a separate post.

Comment: You are right, I will make a separate post. Thanks.